# Is the language $\{\langle A\rangle\mid A\text{ is an NFA and }L(A) = \{0, 1\}^*\}$ decidable?

Tags: formal-languages

How would one go about proving/disproving the language $\{\langle A\rangle \mid A\text{ is an NFA and }L(A) = \{0, 1\}^*\}$ is/isn't decidable?

I assumed at first since it was an NFA involved it would be decidable, but since there is no input string to simulate does this change things? If so, how?

Comment: What does  the notation <A> mean?  Is L(A) the set of strings accepted by A?

Comment: @saulspatz I think it represents the input, we're currently studying turing machines if that helps (if not i'm sorry). And yes L(A) is the language the NFA accepts.

Comment: Since an NFA can be converted to a DFA does that make the language decidable?

Comment: I'm still trying to understand the question.  I don't think it matters that it's an NFA, since as you say, there's an algorithm to convert convert it to a DFA.  What is <A> though?  I'm guessing that it's some kind of encoding for and NFA, so that the question is, "Is there a Turing machine that recognizes all NFA's that accept all binary strings?"  Am I right?

Comment: @saulspatz Essentially yes

Comment: @saultpatz Is the following turing machine description applicable? M = “On input <A> where A is an NFA:
1. Convert NFA A to an equivalent DFA B.
2. Mark the start state of B.
3. Repeat until no new states get marked:
a. Mark any state that has a transition coming into it from any state that is
already marked.
4. If an accept state is marked, accept; otherwise, reject.”

Comment: I don't think so.  This seems like it just detect DFAs that have reachable accepting states, so that you're recognizing DFAs that accept at least one string, rather than DFAs that accept all strings.  I'm guessing that the answer to the question is "yes" though I don't know for sure.  I think we need a theorem that says if a DFA with $n$ states accepts all binary strings of length $\le f(n)$ then it accepts all binary strings.  I've been trying to prove this, but I'm a little hampered by not knowing what $f(n)$ is.  I think something like $n$ or $2n$ probably works.

Comment: @saulspatz Is {0, 1}* potentially infinite? Could this mean the language is undecidable?

Comment: $\{0,1\}^*$ is the set of all finite binary strings, and is most certainly infinite.  I believe I have show in my answer that the question is decidable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes, I think.  Tell me whether you think my proof is correct.

I will prove that if an $n-$ state DFA recognizes all binary strings of length $\le n-1$ then it recognizes all binary strings.  This will prove the theorem, for the Turing machine first converts the input NFA to a DFA.  It the resulting DFA has $n$ states, the Turing simulates the action of the DFA on all bit strings of length $\le n-1,$ and accepts it if and only if all strings are accepted.

Now for the proof.  The DFA accepts $\varepsilon,$ so the starting state is an accepting state.  Since $0$ and $1$ are accepted, any state directly reachable from the starting state is accepted.  Continuing is this manner, we see that every state reachable from the start in at most $n$ steps is accepting.  But there are only $n$ states, so every reachable state is reachable in at most $n-1$ steps, and every state is accepting.

**EDIT** My proof originally said, "Every state is reachable in at most $n+1$ transitions," but it should have said,"Every *reachable* state is reachable in at most $n-1$ transitions."  This isn't important, because the NFA-to-DFA algorithm can prune unreachable states, and if the statement is true for $n-1$ it's true for $n+1,$ but I'm adding the argument if only to reassure myself.

Let T be a reachable state of the DFA, and consider the states visited in processing a string of minimal length that leads to T.  No state is visited twice, because if we visit a state U twice, we can remove the substring processed between the two visits from the input and get a shorter string leading to T.  Since there are no more than $n$ states on the path, there are at most $n-1$ transitions.

Comment: Thanks, I believe this is correct going through it a few times, I appreciate you helping me very much so!

Comment: My pleasure.  Thank you for the problem.  I think it should be $n-1$ not $n+1.$  Not that this matters, just a question of style.

Comment: You suppose that $\{0,1\}$ is the entire alphabet, which is not explicitely stated but very probable. If this is correct, then this problem is called "Universality" and is well-known to be decidable. Probably you should prove your claim for n or n+1, not n-1. For n-1 there is a DFA with n states that accepts all words but no longer word.

Comment: @PeterLeupold I think you left some words out.  What does "accepts all words but no longer word" mean?

Comment: Alright, @saulspatz, I mean "all words up to length n-1" as in your proof sketch.

Comment: @PeterLeupold Thanks.  It sounds like you know what you're talking about, but I haven't been able to confirm your statement.  I can't even construct a 3-state DFA that accepts all string of length <= 2 and no longer strings.  Is this something you can clarify in a comment or should I post a question?

Comment: Maybe you do not count the start state, @saulspatz? States a,b,c, all accepting, a start, transitions a->b with 0,1 and b->c with 0,1. Accepts the empty word, 0, 1, 00, 01, 10 and 11. Nothing else.

Comment: Thank you.  It's been many years since I took automata theory, so maybe I just don't recall it correctly.  I had the same thing, but then I also had a non-accepting state d with c->d on 0,1, d->d on 0,1.  As I recall the definition of DFA that I was taught, you have to have a transition defined for every state/input pair.  Am I wrong?

Comment: You could be right, @saulspatz. What you describe is a COMPLETE DFA, which means every state has to have transitions for every input symbol. In general, completeness is not required. But it is possible that in your course at some point the teacher made the convention that "from now on we require all DFA to be complete." Or that he/she introduced them in the complete form without commenting on that.

Comment: I don't recall after 30+ years.  He said whatever it says in Hopcroft and Ullman, because he basically read us the book.  Thanks for your time.